# No puedo cambiar el color de letra de un textbox que esta dentro de un flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

No se donde está el error pero no me cambia el color de texto cuando ejecuto el programa.

El textbox lo creo en tiempo de ejecución.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listaMIX.Length; i++)
    { 

    TextBox _textbox = new TextBox();               
            _textbox.Text = listaMIX[i].ToString();
            _textbox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            _textbox.Width = 60;
            _textbox.Height = 30;

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(_textbox.Text, "[S]"))
            {
                _textbox.BackColor = Color.Red;
                _textbox.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(_textbox.Text, "[E]"))
            {
                _textbox.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                _textbox.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            }

                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(_textbox);
    }

    Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
    form2.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1);
```

Comment: En que linea exactamente estás intentando cambiar el color? por que lo que quieres es inicializarlo directamente con el color correcto no?

Comment: He probado el código en el evento `Load` de un Form  y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Posiblemente no se cambia el color porque no cumplís ninguna de los 2 Regex

Comment: @HectorLopez lo intent cuando hago el _textbox.ForeColor = Color.White;en cualquier de los dos casos.

Comment: @ElGerar, tienes razón   en un form limpio, funciona.    Seguiré investigando.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal. Las condiciones si se cumplen.

Comment: Gracias por el interés a todos